# How to run a Poisson Process simulation?

Tags: python, simulation

I'm trying to run a simulation for cars arriving into a parking space at Poisson rates (2.5 per minute); parking time is exponential with parameter 45 minutes. This is the code I have but it doesn't seem to work. I get errors on the indents, but nothing runs in the Python shell:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random, math
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import SimPy.Simulation as Sim


class G:
    maxTime = 960.0 # 16 hours * 60 min
    arrivalrate = 2.5 # per min
    parkingtime = 45 # mins
    parkedcars = 0
    seedVal = 9999


class Arrival(Sim.Process):
""" Source generates cars at random
Arrivals are at a time-dependent rate
"""
    def generate(self):
       i=0
       tnow = self.sim.now()
       while (self.sim.now() < 960 ):
          arrivalrate = 2.5 + 10 * math.sin(math.pi * tnow/12.0)
          t = random.expovariate(arrivalrate)
          yield Sim.hold, self, t
          c = Car(name="Car%02d" % (i), sim=self.sim)
          timeParking = random.expovariate(1.0/45)
          self.sim.activate(c, c.visit(timeParking))
          i += ArithmeticError
        
class Car(Sim.Process):
""" Cars arrives, parks for a while, and leaves
Maintain a count of the number of parked cars as cars arrive and leave
"""
    def visit(self, timeParking=0):
        self.sim.parkedcars += 1
        self.sim.parking.observe(self.sim.parkedcars)
        yield Sim.hold, self, timeParking
        self.sim.parkedcars -= 1
        self.sim.parking.observe(self.sim.parkedcars)




class Parkingsim(Sim.Simulation):
    def run(self, aseed):
        random.seed(seed)
        Sim.initialize()
        s = Arrival(name=’Arrivals’, sim=self)
        self.parking = Sim.Monitor(name=’Parking’, ylab=’cars’,
        tlab=’time’, sim=self)
        self.activate(s, s.generate(), at=0.0)
        self.simulate(until=G.maxTime)
        parkinglot = Parkingsim()
        parkinglot.run(1234)


plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,4))
plt.plot(parkinglot.parking.tseries(),parkinglot.parking.yseries())
plt.xlabel(’Time’)
plt.ylabel(’Number of cars’)
plt.xlim(0, 24)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you include an error traceback within your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are having a problem with SimPy.  There are very marked changes between the version for python 2 and python 3.

https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/porting_from_simpy2.html  has a great discussion on what to do with the move from 2 to 3.

Also when using """ you should have triple blocks

```
class Arrival(Sim.Process):
""" Source generates cars at random
Arrivals are at a time-dependent rate
"""
```

should become

```
class Arrival(Sim.Process):
    """ Source generates cars at random
    Arrivals are at a time-dependent rate"""
```

Comment: Your docstring comment is contradicting [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) as well as [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings): "_Note that most importantly, the """ that ends a multiline docstring should be on a line by itself_".